# простой запрос / SQL

Tags: sql

Как вывести клиентов и книги, которые они НЕ заказывали, по таблицам следующего вида (скрин):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицы нужно соединять через JOIN'ы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: попробуй просто отдохнуть :)

Comment: Исходя из приведенных данных, заказы лежат в таблице "Клиент_Книга". Следовательно, нужно вытащить всё, что не пересекается с этой таблицей. только не понятно, как вам нужно соединить Клиента и Книгу через JOIN?

Comment: помножить все клиенты на все книги, потом присоединить заказы и отфильтровать заказанное.

Comment: зы: в чем схема рисовалась?

Comment: @teran вот тут https://app.creately.com/d/CSV8OV36YZA/edit/s/pypGEaDVLa6

Comment: @SergeyK. На данный момент действую в рамках учебного курса: такое задание попалось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение. Это для MS SQL Server, но вы можете изменить его для любой СУБД.

CTE получает все возможные комбинации между клиентами и книгами через `CROSS JOIN`, затем `EXCEPT` отфильтровывает уже заказанные книги.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @customer TABLE (custID INT PRIMARY KEY, cust_name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @customer (custID, cust_name) VALUES
(1, 'Anna'),
(2, 'Lena');

DECLARE @book TABLE (bookID INT PRIMARY KEY, book_title VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @book (bookID, book_title) VALUES
(1, 'War and Peace'),
(2, 'Anna Karenina');

DECLARE @customer_book TABLE (custID INT, bookID INT);
INSERT @customer_book (custID, bookID) VALUES
(1, 1);
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT * FROM @customer;
SELECT * FROM @book;
SELECT * FROM @customer_book;

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.custID, b.bookID 
    FROM @customer AS c
        CROSS JOIN @book AS b
    EXCEPT
    SELECT custID, bookID FROM @customer_book
)
SELECT c.*, b.book_title
FROM rs
    INNER JOIN @customer AS c ON c.custID = rs.custID
    INNER JOIN @book AS b ON b.bookID = rs.bookID
ORDER BY c.cust_name, b.book_title;
```

**Результат**

| custID | cust_name | book_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | Anna Karenina |
| 2 | Lena | Anna Karenina |
| 2 | Lena | War and Peace |

Comment: достататочно было `from a,b, left join c where c.x is null`

Comment: огромное спасибо!
мне удалось решить проблему несколько иначе (клиенты cross join книги where (cust_id,book_id) NOT IN (select * from клиенты_книги) ), но узнать про EXCEPT было крайне полезно